# Como exibir um resultado usando 2 selects

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-select, tabela-html

Possuo duas tabela, Produtos e Pedidos.

Eu preciso criar um `combobox` para produtos e quando o usuário  escolher um produto, a página tem que exibir todos os pedidos relacionado com o produto, se eu escolher outro produto tem que mudar os pedidos.

Estou pensando em usar um Select da tabela produto para gerar os produtos e depois pegar o id do produto selecionado e fazer um select com a tabela pedidos.

Ex.:

```
Produto: Detergente          
 button: Gerar relatório

Pedido|Quantidade

0123  | 2 und

0258  | 100 und
```

Código abaixo:

```
Produto:<SELECT NAME="produto"  required="1" onchange="geratabela()">
            <option>Selecione...</option>
            <?php
            $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw");
            if (!$conexao) die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error()); 
            mysql_select_db('Varejo', $conexao);
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM produto ORDER BY cod_prod, nome ASC";
            $q1 = mysql_query($query1);
            while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
            {   
            ?>
             <option value="<?=$dados['cod_prod'] ?>">
            <?=$dados['nome'] ?>
            </option>
            <?php
                }
                ?>

                </SELECT><br><br>

        <?      
                function geratabela() {

                 ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
                error_reporting( E_ALL );
                $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw");
                if (!$conexao) die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error()); 
                mysql_select_db('Varejo', $conexao);
                $cod_prod = $_GET["cod_prod"];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedido where cod_prod=$cod_prod";
                $q = mysql_query($sql);
                //tabela com os dados


                }
                ?>
```

Comment: O que você já tem? Seu problema é no select ou no combo box ? Ou ambos?

Comment: Usa Ajax, utiliza o onchange do select ou o onclick do button para fazer a consulta por ajax...

Comment: @Guerra na verdade eu tenho só a tela montada mas estou pensando na lógica por isso perguntei pq não sou muito bom em programação.

Comment: @MayronCeccon Obrigado vou pesquisar na internet, vc tem algum site de referência ?

Comment: @GustavoB se estiver utilizando Jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ou somente JS http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ e para criar a tabela http://www.arquivodecodigos.net/dicas/javascript-como-criar-um-tabela-elemento-html-table-dinamicamente-contendo-linhas-e-colunas-3322.html

Comment: @MayronCeccon    Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @MayronCeccon eu gerei um código Ajax no bloco de notas(deixei o note em casa), vou deixar ele junto com a pegunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso você está tentando chamar um método PHP que é "server side" com javascript que é "client side" nesse caso.

O ideal é fazer um outro arquivo para tratar sua solicitação AJAX por exemplo:

```
//fiz alterações para usar o PDO do php
```

[veja motivo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

```
//aqui vamos verificar se seu parametro foi passado
if(!isset($_POST["cod_prod"]){
    echo '';
    exit;
}
ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Varejo;charset=utf8";
$conexao = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'usbw');    
$cod_prod[] = $_POST["cod_prod"]; // o ideal aqui é sanitizar os dados para não ter problema de segurança
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM pedido where cod_prod= ?');
$stmt->execute($cod_prod);
$ret = "<ul>"; // aqui vamos começar montar o html de retorno
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $value){
   $ret .= "<li>$value</li>";
}
$ret .= "</ul>";
echo $ret;
```

seu html ficaria assim vamos chamar o arquivo de cima de pedidos.php

exemplo ajax:

```
<javascript>
function getPedidos(valor){
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
  url: "pedidos.php",
  data: { cod_prod: valor }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    //faz algo com o valor retornado
  });
}
```

Recomendo usar [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar e te darei o retorno. No caso do ajax eu implementaria ele no html? E o link para JQuery esta apontado para o link errado.

Comment: Isso o Ajax Implementa no html, arrumei  o link. Lembre-se de carregar a lib. Outra coisa, não testei o código então talvez precise de alguns ajustes. Boa sorte

Comment: opa  consegui arrumar a parte do html, consegui resolver o problema